# How to OTA update through native api's in esp32?

Tags: embedded, embedded-linux, freertos, ota, esp32

I'm using the native app skd to perform ota. In which i change the firmware version number to '2' and ota works fine as soon as i restart my esp module.How ever restarting it again leads to this error :

(4791) native_ota_example: New firmware version: 2

I (4791) native_ota_example: Running firmware version: 1

I (4911) native_ota_example: Last invalid firmware version: 2

W (4911) native_ota_example: New version is the same as invalid version.

W (4911) native_ota_example: Previously, there was an attempt to launch the firmware with 2 version, but it failed.

W (4921) native_ota_example: The firmware has been rolled back to the previous version.

Now i do understand that rollback has occurred as i have configured the APP_ROLLBACK_ENABLE Macro with 'y'.
But if i dont iinitialsie this macro then firmware update only occurs if i flash the whole native sdk again .
Please Help.

The firmware update should work everytime i restart or if not the new app should load.